# How do I make a placeholder image in HTML if the original image hasn't been found?

Tags: html, css

Basically what the title says.

I'm making an html page, and using images for link. But can I make it so the images show a default icon if the specified file hasn't been found?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you specify the width and height of an image in the css, you can set the background image as a not-found image:

```css
img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/vyAs27) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="not-found.png" /><img src="http://goo.gl/ijai22" />
```

Most browsers will insert an image missing icon in the corner. There's no way that I know of to remove this.

As you can see, your regular image will overlay the background image.

If your image has a transparent background then the background image will be visible behind the loaded image.

Alternatively, use a server-side programming language that checks if the image exists. If it does not, load a placeholder...

Comment: You could also use `<img>`'s onerror handler to set the src using javascript.

Answer (score 50):

You'll have to use javascript:

```
<img src="404image" onerror="this.src='images/not_found.png';" />
```

Comment: In addition a resource for none inline handlers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512539/javascript-onload-and-onerror-called-together

Comment: As this is now deprecated, is there any replacement?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display a blank space without any dummy image/caption, remove the alt option that you have specified in the `img` tag.

```
<img src='not_found.jpg' alt='' class=''>
```

Here the source `not_found.jpg` is the wrong path which won't give any image.
PFA for sample o/p.

- Here 1st image is showing when it gets valid src & the 2nd one shows the blank space without any caption.

[image: Here 1st image is showing when it gets valid src & the 2nd one shows the blank space without any caption.]

Comment: Unfortunately, the blank space will be collapsed unless `width` and `height` are set in the `img` tag

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: url(https://i0.wp.com/reviveyouthandfamily.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/house-placeholder.jpg?ssl=1) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="not-found.png" /><img src="https://i0.wp.com/reviveyouthandfamily.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/house-placeholder.jpg?ssl=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution without a background image and without JS. It uses a pseudo element in CSS. See it answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209608/3177115