# how to modify img src unless the result breaks the image url

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have a script I've written designed for Tumblr, which modifies part of the img src in inline images (in text/caption/etc posts, NOT photo/photoset posts) to display larger, as the default url loaded into Tumblr forces them to be 500px or less, and many images are often bigger and can be stretched to fill their container. However, sometimes the url for larger images isn't always available, and I wanted to know if there was a way to cancel the script on that particular image if if changing the url breaks it. This is what I have, but it blinks on the page:

```
$( window ).on( "load", function(){
$('.tmblr-full img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
        $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('_500.','_540.'))
    if ($(this).width() >= 500) {
        $(this).css({'width' : 'auto', 'height' : 'auto'});
    }
})

$('.tmblr-full img').error(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
        $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('_540.','_500.'))
})

});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeongguk/48hpeo9z) with the original code (not including the error function I added) so you can see the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What url does tumbler return if the image does not exits?

Comment: @TonyHensler It doesn't return anything, the image simply breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my method, I used ajax to check if the new image URL is valid (does not return any error codes) and only change the URL if the ajax call succeeds.

```
$(".tmblr-full img").each(function(){ // for every img inside a .tmblr-full

  var img = $(this), // define the target image
  newSrc = img.attr("src").replace("_500.","_540."); // the image source to check

  $.ajax({ // run an ajax check on the new image source
    url:newSrc,
    success: function(){ // if the image is found
      img.attr("src",newSrc); // replace the old url with the new one
    }
  });

});
```

(Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/48hpeo9z/7/)

But because Tumblr includes the original width of the image with its `<figure>` tags, you could also use that to check if a larger version of the image exists.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the URL from a string to a different string - how can the system know whether the second string will cause an error, or not?

What you *could* do is to redefine also the [onload and onerror handlers of that particular image, as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512539/javascript-onload-and-onerror-called-together), as well as saving the previous URL value into an attribute of that img. Then, if an error condition fires, you clear both onload and onerror and re-set the previous src value.

## My attempt :-)

I'm not currently able to try it out, but here it goes:

```
$('.tmblr-full img').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);
    var img  = $img[0];

    // Save the original src
    $img.attr('orig-src', $img.attr('src'));

    img.onerror = function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        var orig = $img.attr('orig-src');
        $img.attr('orig-src', null);
        $img.attr('src', orig);
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        if ($img.width() >= 500) {
            $img.css({'width' : 'auto', 'height' : 'auto'});
        }
    }
    // Now try loading.
    // If I remember correctly this will either fire onload
    // or onerror.
    img.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('_500.','_540.'));
})
```

Comment: I know very little to nothing of Javascript yet, unfortunately. How would I incorporate this into the existing script, or write it anew? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, the very last line is $ img not img. I'll correct it tomorrow from my pc.

Comment: I tested the script and it doesn't work. :( You can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/jeongguk/48hpeo9z/3/